# Getting FileNotFound Exception when adding project dependency to a project which uses another Nuget Package

Tags: c#, .net

I have a setup with Project A which is NetStandard Library project. Another Project A.Frame is Net Framework Library project with the common Class File Class1.cs(Class1.cs is linked file in both the projects). Class1.cs has a function FooA() which returns "Netstandard" if the Project type is of Netstandard and "NetFramework" when the project type is NetFramework. Another Project in the same Solution Project B has a function FooB() which calls the function FooA() and returns the result.
I have packaged this entire setup in a Nuget Package such that the Bait and Switch will allow the both Netstandard and NetFramework to use their respective dll's.
Now I use the Nuget Package in a Different Project of a Different Solution say Project C of Solution B. Project C is a NetStandard Library Project with a function Bar() which calls the function FooB() from Project B. When I try to test this on a Unit Test Project using the Project dependency to Project C I get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

When I use the Nuget Package on a NetFramework Library I get the desired output.
Is there something I am missing or I need to do with my Nuget Package settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are your projects using packages.config or the new PackageReference format? Dependency resolution with PackageReference uses a [transitive restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution) process. With .NET Standard, packages.config [isn't fully supported](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31).